# Determine which exploit was used on a pcap file of attack

Tags: wireshark, computer-forensics

I have a pcap file which contains the attack to a local server environment I made. The attack to the local was made using Metasploit Framework on another Kali Linux machine and the traffic was captured with Wireshark using port mirroring on the router. I was able to exploit the system and get the local password.

The question is, how do I know which exploit I have used just by looking on the pcap file? I would like to give that file for forensic analysis.

Is there any way to find the exploit name on the pcap file?

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further investigations, I was able to figure it out how to know which **exploit** has been used on the attack. I managed to configure **SNORT**, a **IDS system**, on my Kali Linux machine and pass the `*.pcap` file to it.

Snort will analyze that `*.pcap` file trying to find all traffic that matches for certain rules. If any traffic behavior matches with any snort rules, snort will prompt you with a message.

Taking this into account, I was able to gather exploit name after a match of the rule **exploit.rules** in Snort folder.
Snort has plenty of rules by default on his rules folder, so you just need to run the following command to the `*.pcap` file and pray for a match ;)

```
snort -r <your-pcap-file>
```

I hope this help to anyone who is trying to find which exploit has been used on a attack that was captured by tcpdump or wireshark.